# How to hide Magento category menu on other cms pages

Tags: php, magento, menu, magento-1.9

I've created a main menu (different from the Magneto categories menu) which I want to be the only menu displayed when my clients aren't shopping.

Basically, what I want is a method or a condition to tell Magneto to display the Magneto categories menu ONLY if some wants to shop online (when they click on Shop Online) and to hide it when people are on other pages.

My main menu consists of 
Shop Online | Collections | About | Booking | Contact

And the Magento Menu consists of
Suits | Shirts | Blazers | etc... (which are the categories)

I am looking for a way to hide the Magento Menu when am in Collections, About, Booking, Contact (which are cms pages) but being able to display it when in Shop Online (which is .landing page for categories)

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this on your cms pages (Collections, About, Booking, Contact), in back-end Cms > Page > Manage content > Design > Page Layout > Layout Update XML part.

To remove the "magento categories menu" you can set:

```
<reference name="header">
<remove name="top.menu" />
</reference>
```

You can add your new custom menu block in this part too.